# Jenkins: Couldn't find any revision to build

Tags: ros, jenkins, build

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My project complies just file, and I am expecting ROS to generate my docs, but I keep receiving a failure!

The console log located here:
http://jenkins.ros.org/job/devel-hydro-ar_sys/61/console

What shall I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192958/jenkins:-couldn%27t-find-any-revision-to-build/) by [sahloul](https://answers.ros.org/users/20184/sahloul/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From the console output you linked to:

> ERROR: Couldn't find any revision to build. Verify the repository and branch configuration for this job.

From [rosdistro/master/hydro/distribution.yaml](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/hydro/distribution.yaml#L140-L154):

```
  ar_sys:
    doc:
      type: git
      url: https://github.com/Sahloul/ar_sys.git
      version: hydro-devel
[..]
    source:
      type: git
      url: https://github.com/Sahloul/ar_sys.git
      version: hydro-devel
    status: developed
```

The rosdistro `doc` entry points to a `hydro-devel` branch, but that doesn't seem to exist in your repository (there is only a `master` branch).

You should update the rosdistro entries for `ar_sys` to point to the correct branch. I expect it will start working then.

Your `source` entry also points to `hydro-devel`.

---

Also: have you instructed Bloom to use your source repository as a release repository?

Edit: yes, that is 'wrong'. The [Releasing a Package for the First Time](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease) tutorial clearly tells you (just above [Section 2. Creating a Release Repository](http://wiki.ros.org/bloom/Tutorials/FirstTimeRelease#line-16)):

> Next, let's talk about how bloom works. **First, bloom requires that you have a separate "release" repository for releasing your package**. This repository must be a git repository and is normally hosted. For example, all of the ROS release repositories are in the ros-gbp github organization. These repositories are the result of running bloom on a repository containing one or more catkin packages. We highly recommend that you host your release repository on https://github.com.

(emphasis mine).

Bloom takes all sorts of precautions, but it might clobber branches you have in your source repository, if it needs those for the release process. I'd recommend creating a release repository (as it says in the tutorial).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sahloul](https://answers.ros.org/users/20184/sahloul/) on 2014-09-18**:
Thank you, it seems that's it... and Yes, I did that with bloom, is that also wrong?